# How to format URL for GET Request in Webmatrix

Tags: razor, webmatrix

I'm working on a simple CRUD application to keep track of phones using Webmatrix 3. My `Default.cshtml` file displays the table. 
When clicking on a row it goes to the `EditPN.cshtml` page for the user to edit the information for that record.
Now, following [this tutorial](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/data/5-working-with-data) I look into the value of `UrlData[0]` in my `EditPN` page.

Everything works fine with just one problem: since the URL ends up being something like this: 
`http://localhost:64053/EditPN/2223334444` my paths for CSS and JS files are off. My brute force solution has been to have both:

```
<link href="_css/myStyles.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="../_css/myStyles.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

in my `_Layout.cshtml`.

That way both `http://localhost:64053/Default.cshtml` and `http://localhost:64053/EditPN/222333444` will have the CSS styles.

Since I don't like that, I tried to format the URL string to be this: `http://localhost:64053/EditPN?pn=2223334444`. Didn't work.

Tried this too: `http://localhost:64053/EditPN.cshtml?pn=2223334444`. Didn't work either. It doesn't even go to the `EditPN.cshtml` page.

How can I solve this issue? Oh, and BTW, I don't want to use the Webmatrix helpers. I want to keep things under JS, jQuery, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should prefix the url to your css and js files with a ~/, which tells web pages to work out the relative path:

```
<link href="~/_css/myStyles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Comment: BTW, I discovered your site today when I was searching for an answer to this.. I really want to get good at Webmatrix with jQuery. I have some vary basic experience with both. I'll look around your site. Suggestions are welcome!